# Using client object model to trigger Content Organizer Rule

Tags: client-object-model, file-upload, records-center

Using the client object model of sharepoint (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client) i'm trying building a client that will upload documents into the "Drop Off Library" within a record center site.

I can upload the document into the library, set the content type and other columns.

But I can't seem to set off the Content Organizer Rule(s) once i have uploaded the document.

From other online documentation i have found i see that using the "full client" you can use `OfficialFileCore.SubmitFile`, but what can be done for the client side approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope following blog will helps,

http://blog.scosby.com/post/2011/03/16/SharePoint-2010-Content-Organizer-Client-Object-Model.aspx